# Question related to Noncommuting Operators in Hilbert spaces

Tags: operator-theory

We denote by ${\bf \large G}(n,d)$  the set of all functions $f$ from $\{1,2, ... , n\} $ to the set  $\{1.2...,d\}$. For $f\in {\bf \large G}$, we set ${\bf A_f}:=A_{f(1)}\cdots A_{f(n)}$.

Let ${\bf A}=(A_1,...,A_d) \in \mathcal{L}(E)^d$. I want to show the 
 the following assertion:

Let $m,n$ such that $1\leq m\leq n$, why we have

$$\sum_{h\in {\bf \large G}(n-m,d)} {\bf A}_h^*\left(\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(m,d)} {\bf A}_g^* {\bf A}_{g}\right) {\bf A}_{h}=\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d)} {\bf A}_g^* {\bf A}_{g}\; ??$$

And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, note that you can write the following

$$
\begin{align*}
\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(n,d)} {\bf T}_g^* {\bf T}_{g} & =\sum_{h\in {\bf \large G}(n-m,d)} {\bf T}_h^*\left(\sum_{g\in {\bf \large G}(m,d)} {\bf T}_g^* {\bf T}_{g}\right) {\bf T}_{h} \\
& = \sum_{h \in {\bf \large G}(n-m,d), g \in {\bf \large G}(m,d)} ({\bf T}_{g\star h})^* {\bf T}_{g \star h}
\end{align*}
$$
where $g \star h$ is a function from $\{1,2, \ldots n\}$ to $\{1,2, \ldots, d\}$ such that $(g\star h)(k) = g(k)$ for $k \leq m$ and $(g \star h)(m+k) = h(k)$ for $k \geq 1$. Then you just have to establish that
$$
\star: {\bf \large G}(m,d)\times {\bf \large G}(n-m,d) \to {\bf \large G}(n,d): (g,h) \mapsto g \star h
$$
is a bijection, which isn't hard to do.

As for the second question, maybe you could use the previous result in a proof by induction on $m$?

Comment: TFor my answer in the assertion 2 if the second inequality is true or not?? Thank you very much